# Detect Trends in a chart

Tags: python, detection, trend

I want to know how can I detect trends in such a chart as below. I can detect with my eyes but how can I detect it programmatically(Python, C#, ...)?[image]

Comment: what do you mean by trends? Can you define it in more detail in your question?

Comment: Can you see the orange arrows over the chart? in the first part chart has an uptrend then stationary and uptrend again. How can I find these trends by programming?

Comment: What I mean is that you need to define your requirements. For example the last arrow might have an average slope of 0.02. Does that count as "horizontal"? What about 0.06? Those are questions we can't guess. It would help you to think those things in detail :)

Comment: Tnx for your response. Take +/- 10 degrees as a range trend. more than 10 degrees is ascending trend and less than -10 is descending trend. The main question is how can we simpilfy a toleranced chart like the picture to some straight lines.